# Strange signup pattern on website detected

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, spam-prevention

I launched my first web app (`node/express` backend, running on a `Heroku` server) into production last week, and already I am seeing some strange signup behaviour in the logs.

At first I though that it was real users, but it's happened enough times with the same pattern for it to be clearly some sort of spam bot.

My website contains a signup `form` that requires a `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `password1` and `password2` (must match). On submitting the form, users must then click an additional button to select the type of account they wish to register for, and an email is sent to the provided address for validation.

For the past few days I've had a number (around 10) suspicious signups with a browsing pattern like below (two examples from last night):

```
timestamp    page

04:48:45    viewBlogPage
04:48:47    registerUser
[ Send email for user to verify ]
04:48:54    sendResetToken
04:48:56    sendResetToken
04:48:58    getBlogPost
04:49:10    getBlogPost
04:49:12    getBlogPost
04:49:15    getBlogPost
04:49:15    getBlogPost

22:22:32    viewBlogPage
22:22:32    registerUser
[ Send email for user to verify ]
22:22:38    sendResetToken
22:22:39    sendResetToken
22:22:40    getBlogPost
22:22:41    getBlogPost
22:22:42    getBlogPost
22:22:42    getBlogPost
22:22:43    getBlogPost
```

In every case, the `user` has:

1. Navigated to the main blog page (which contains a list of blog posts)
2. Navigated to the signup page, entered valid `form` data and submitted the form. In every case, the `firstname` and `lastname` are nonsensical, seemingly random character strings (e.g. `firstname: 'Iluuxpmv', lastname: 'Yrtkaugn'` and `firstname: 'Qatocgyp', lastname: 'Hdfurawghgkqs'`)
3. An email is sent that does not get verified
4. The `user` then navigates to the login page and attempts to reset their password twice in quick succession
5. The `user` then navigates to one particular blog post five times

My first question is **How can I stop this**?

More broadly though, I'm interested in why these (presumably) bots are navigating my site in this weird way.

If this is a spam bot, it seems strange that this has only happened around 10 times, and that they are then clicking on non-random pages that don't contain forms.

**Is there some explanation for what is going on that might help me prevent against this?**

Comment: how about placing a captcha during login or ask to do some mathematical calculation

Comment: What is the purpose of preventing it?

Comment: @brk - If that's the best way then I guess I could look into that, but to me it always seems like a bad user experience!

Comment: @Archer - it's a good question. I guess mainly it's that I'm worried that this will scale up (10,000 fake signups a day), which fills up my database with unverified users. I'm also worried that the email addresses are real, and that I will get reported for spamming them, and my sender score will be lowered

Comment: There's nothing you can do about the fake signups with real email addresses, unfortunately, but it's unlikely to happen too often.  As for the database, just remove registered users that haven't verified after a day or two.  Do that once a day (with a scheduled task) and it will keep the garbage out of the DB.  There are other things you can do to cut down on the noise, but nothing to stop it completely.  Do you keep the IP address of each registration?

Comment: Not sure what type of server you're running, but if available, you could check your request/access logs. These mostly contain request headers etc where you can get more info about the "bot/user" like from where they requested the urls, what kind of user-agent, ..  If it is a bot, then you can block that user agent for example.

Comment: @Archer - why is it unlikely to happen too often?

Comment: @BertMaurau - It's on a Heroku server. Checking my logs, I have this information:   `Oct 15 19:42:22 heroku/router at=info method=GET path="/blog" host=www.researching.io request_id=1a136d9c-9483-46d5-99b4-fb7085beae19 fwd="<IP address>" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=38ms status=200 bytes=11369 protocol=https`.

Comment: @fugu That's neither here nor there.  If you can discern a pattern that is close enough to catch most of the fake attempts, without false positives, then you can use that to handle these attempts.

Comment: It's not simply crawling the site so I'd be surprised if the user agent was not a common one that you'd see from a browser.

Comment: @Archer - that's interesting. Do you have any links where I could read up about this sort of thing? Might be useful as an answer?

Comment: No - it's something you'd do on a case-by-case basis.  Also, if you find a way to identify potential bots then *__allow them to register and post__*.  Just don't let them see real site data and flag their posts so they're never shown on the real site.  That way they look like they're working and the owner will feel all happy and go about their business without trying to further circumvent your protection.

Comment: @Archer OK, that's basically what I'm doing, as unverified users can't enter the site proper. What do you mean by `"user agent was not a common one that you'd see from a browser."`?

Comment: Just google for user agents.  You'll see the common ones in browsers like chrome, edge etc., but can change that to anything you want when you make a web request.  Spiders often identify themselves via the user agent, but I wouldn't expect a spam bot to do that as it doesn't want you to know it's not a real person.

Comment: Honestly, until this becomes an actual problem then just do a load of reading about it.  It's a vast topic and often approached unnecessarily.  Just make sure you've read enough to know how *you* want to approach it.  Don't pick a standard method for dealing with it, as that only works today.  They'll get round it tomorrow.  Be unexpected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is "How do I stop this?", then the answer is that you may not be able to stop it altogether, but you can add in some additional security or verification. Ideally add security measures on the server side, as this is strongly arguable that that's where security actually happens. Verification can happen client-side also, but it's just that it can be undone, or bypassed more easily.

Some quick wins can be -

**Whitelist not blacklist**

Don't sit and work through a number of conditions in which your validation should catch an error. This will very quickly become outdated, and you'll have to update it. i.e. Don't blacklist certain values or conditions, and then all others that are uncaught are passed.

Instead, whitelist - so provide a set of conditions by which your verification DOES pass. Then everything that doesn't pass that - fails, and is not submitted. This allows your application to always continue allowing content that you've ensured it's allowed to, and all other changing input / bypass techniques, fail.

**Add A Timer To Your Registration Pages**

A normal user will take at least a few seconds to input their details and choose a suitable password etc - whereas a bot will not. A bot will execute the script almost immediately. This means you could implement a timer, and on submit on the form check if the timer is less than 3 seconds or so. If it is, prevent the submit and redirect the user.

**Rename Your Email Field And Misdirect**

Instead of having a single email field, you could have two, but with one being hidden.

```
<input type="hidden" value="" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email..."> 
<input type="email" value="" name="eee" id="eee" placeholder="Enter your email...">
```

A bot will search for any fields and try to input valid inputs to be successfully submitted. So a bot will find the now fake hidden field "email" and fill it out, however a regular user should **not** be able to see that field. Therefore, when the form submits, simply check if the hidden field has any value in it, other than an empty string.

**Ensure No Inputs Are Equal**

A lot of spam bots just input the same values into every input. While this doesn't seem to be the case with your given example, it is a regular occurrence. They might just input `iamafakebot@fakeemail.com` for the first name, last name, email, AND password - assuming that this will allow successful submission against the fields it expects.

Therefore, you can compare your submitted values, and if they equal one another, you can not submit your form, and even present a message that would be readable to a user.

**Conclusion**

This may not solve your problem in totality, as security is a massive topic, with many varying opinions and ever updating conditions - however, these will at the very least add some additional security to your application.

Hopefully, one of these is applicable in your scenario, and you start to see fewer bots in your system.

Comment: Thanks. Some useful thoughts here. I had thought about renaming the email field, and I think that this is the first thing I'll try. Timing seems risky as real users might use autocomplete, which might trigger anti-bot defences bases on timing.